# parallel running of threads unreliable behaviour

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I've wrote the following program. I expect that this function print 1, 2 sequentially but 
the program waits some time(for example 10 sec) and then prints all of the result.

here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg);
char message[] = "Hello World";

int run_now = 1;

int main() 
{
    int res;

    pthread_t a_thread;
    void *thread_result;

    res = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, thread_function, (void *)message);
    if (res != 0) 
    {
        perror("Thread creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int print_count1 = 0;
    while(print_count1++ < 20) 
    {
        if (run_now == 1) 
        {
            printf("1");
            run_now = 2;
        }
        else 
        {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    printf("\nWaiting for thread to finish...\n");

    res = pthread_join(a_thread, &thread_result);
    if (res != 0) 
    {
        perror("Thread join failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Thread joined. \n");    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *thread_function(void *arg) 
{
    int print_count2 = 0;
    while(print_count2++ < 20) 
    {
        if (run_now == 2) 
        {
            printf("2");
            run_now = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

i expect to 1, 2 be printed every 1 seconds, but program is waiting some times and then prints all of the string entirely. can anybody tell me what's the reason?

Comment: try it with `printf("2\n");`.

Comment: `run_now` needs to be protected or made atomic, your code as it is has a data race => undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few problems with your program. First, `printf` may buffer things internally, so you won't see them. This is probably what you refer to. You need to `fflush` `stdout` after each `printf`. The more serious problem is that your program is wrong, as it uses a non-atomic, non-volatile variable for communication.

In your `thread_function`, the compiler is free to move the load of `run_now` out of the loop and only work with a register copy, hence the loop won't ever notice that another thread changed the value in memory. You should always use atomic intrinsics to access shared variables like this.

Comment: your first part of answer is completely true. but as you mentioned in second part if second thread work with a copy of `run_now` then the thread never be terminated and because of sleep it is always in idle state. so compiler doesn't perform this situation. am i right?

Comment: you can't rely on compiler not doing it, it's fully entitled to change its mind anytime; use atomics (and I don't mean WMDs :-) or if you have to, mutexes/critical sections

Answer (score 3):

`int run_now` is accessed concurrently and therefore its access **needs** to be protected.

To do so use a mutex for example:

```
...

int run_now = 1;
pthtread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main() 
{
    ...

    while(print_count1++ < 20) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        int run_now_equals_1 = (run_now == 1);
        if (run_now_equals_1)
        {
            printf("1");
            run_now = 2;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if (!run_now_equals_1)
        {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    ...
}

void *thread_function(void *arg) 
{
    int print_count2 = 0;

    while(print_count2++ < 20) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        int run_now_equals_2 = (run_now == 2);
        if (run_now_equals_2) 
        {
            printf("2");
            run_now = 1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if (!run_now_equals_2)
        {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, pthread mutexes are extremely expensive compared to atomic compare and swap (although more portable).

Answer (score 1):

Use `fprintf(stderr,"...")` instead of `printf`, or add a `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf`.

This is because `stout` is flushed only when OS decides to flush it, while `stderr` is flushed as soon as `fprintf` is called.

Comment: As far as I know, stdout and stderr are no different from each other as far as the (POSIX, anyway) operating system is concerned. They are just file descriptors. Also, if you print to `stderr` but flush `stdout` it's not going to do much good. :-)

Comment: @mornfall I said fprintf(stderr,"...") OR printf+fflush(stdout). I don't know if they are different but I know that the output of printf is shown when OS decides to print, while fprintf(stderr..., prints at real time.

Comment: Actually, fflush and stderr autoflush is not OS, it's just libc.